# bash IO redirection with tee, without complicated syntax, how it works?

Tags: bash, io

One way to do *implicit* `dup(2)` in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) with the output in `fd` `{10,11,12}` in a *real use-case* and close it right after, based [on this](https://superuser.com/questions/1769886/bash-one-liner-to-read-stdin-and-print-last-10-matches-each-for-2-separate-patte/1770450#1770450):

```
$ cat tags
desktop-19.9.0
foobar-1.2.3
desktop-22.9.0
mobile-24.10.0
desktop-18.9.0
desktop-21.9.0
mobile-23.10.0
foobar-1.2.4
desktop-17.8.0
desktop-20.8.0
mobile-22.9.0
desktop-16.8.0
desktop-19.8.0
mobile-21.9.0
foobar-1.2.5
desktop-15.7.0
desktop-18.7.0
mobile-20.8.0
desktop-14.7.0
desktop-17.7.0
mobile-19.8.0
desktop-13.6.0
desktop-16.6.0
mobile-18.7.0
foobar-1.2.6
desktop-12.6.0
desktop-15.6.0
mobile-17.7.0
desktop-11.5.0
desktop-14.5.0
mobile-16.6.0
desktop-10.5.0
desktop-13.5.0
mobile-15.6.0
desktop-9.4.0
desktop-12.4.0
mobile-14.5.0
desktop-8.4.0
desktop-11.4.0
mobile-13.5.0
desktop-7.3.0
foobar-1.2.7
desktop-10.3.0
mobile-12.4.0
desktop-6.3.0
desktop-9.3.0
mobile-11.4.0
desktop-5.2.0
desktop-8.2.0
mobile-10.3.0
desktop-4.2.0
desktop-7.2.0
mobile-9.3.0
desktop-3.1.0
desktop-6.1.0
mobile-8.2.0
desktop-2.1.0
desktop-5.1.0
mobile-7.2.0
desktop-1.0.0
foobar-1.2.8
desktop-4.0.0
mobile-6.1.0
```

```
cat tags        | tee  /dev/fd/{10,11,12} 10> >(
grep -w desktop | tail -n 3) 11> >(
grep -w mobile  | tail -n 3) 12> >(
grep -w foobar  | tail -n 3) 1>/dev/null
```

##### Output:

```
foobar-1.2.6
foobar-1.2.7
foobar-1.2.8
mobile-8.2.0
mobile-7.2.0
mobile-6.1.0
desktop-5.1.0
desktop-1.0.0
desktop-4.0.0
```

It's works, but I have no explanations on *how it works*. What's happens under the hood?

Why the `fd` auto-close is not clear for me. Could it be written using explicit open/close `fd`?

```
test -e /dev/fd/10 && echo open || echo close
close
```

**Edit**:

Could be simplified as:

```
cat tags         | tee >(
grep -w mobile   | tail -n3) >(
grep -w desktop  | tail -n3) >(
grep -w foobar   | tail -n3) > /dev/null
```

**Debug syscalls**:

```
$ strace -fff -o log bash -c '
cat tags         | tee >(
grep -w mobile   | tail -n3) >(
grep -w desktop  | tail -n3) >(
grep -w foobar   | tail -n3) > /dev/null'

$ less log.*

$ grep dup log*
log.2476802:dup2(4, 1)                              = 1
log.2476803:dup2(3, 0)                              = 0
log.2476803:dup2(4, 63)                             = 63
log.2476803:dup2(4, 62)                             = 62
log.2476803:dup2(4, 61)                             = 61
log.2476803:dup2(3, 1)                              = 1
log.2476804:dup2(3, 0)                              = 0
log.2476805:dup2(4, 1)                              = 1
log.2476806:dup2(3, 0)                              = 0
log.2476807:dup2(3, 0)                              = 0
log.2476808:dup2(4, 1)                              = 1
log.2476809:dup2(3, 0)                              = 0
log.2476810:dup2(3, 0)                              = 0
log.2476811:dup2(4, 1)                              = 1
log.2476812:dup2(3, 0)                              = 0

$ LANG=C grep close log.*
log.2476801:close(3)                                = 0
log.2476801:close(4)                                = 0
log.2476801:close(4)                                = -1 EBADF (Mauvais descripteur de fichier)
log.2476801:close(3)                                = -1 EBADF (Mauvais descripteur de fichier)
log.2476802:close(4)                                = 0
log.2476802:close(3)                                = 0
log.2476802:close(1)                                = 0
log.2476802:close(2)                                = 0
log.2476803:close(3)                                = 0
log.2476803:close(4)                                = 0
log.2476803:close(3)                                = 0
log.2476803:close(4)                                = 0
log.2476803:close(3)                                = 0
log.2476803:close(4)                                = 0
log.2476803:close(3)                                = 0
log.2476803:close(3)                                = 0
log.2476803:close(3)                                = 0
log.2476803:close(3)                                = 0
log.2476803:close(3)                                = 0
log.2476803:close(3)                                = 0
log.2476803:close(3)                                = 0
log.2476803:close(3)                                = 0
log.2476803:close(3)                                = 0
log.2476803:close(4)                                = 0
log.2476803:close(5)                                = 0
log.2476803:close(0)                                = 0
log.2476804:close(63)                               = 0
log.2476804:close(4)                                = -1 EBADF (Mauvais descripteur de fichier)
log.2476804:close(3)                                = 0
log.2476804:close(3)                                = -1 EBADF (Mauvais descripteur de fichier)
[...]
```

Related: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution

Comment: I'm also curious about what determines the order of the output. It seems to be deterministic. I just tried your input and command under Windows/Cygwin, and the result is the same order as yours.

Comment: Good question, I have no clue ^^

Comment: With `tee` reading inputs and writing outputs per block, it is normal to have all the outputs grouped per processes. With a larger `tags` file, we would surely have interleaved output. I guess the order of the `tee` outputs depends of the way `bash` is programmed. Here it is the reverse order. But `cat >(/bin/echo 1) 2>(/bin/echo 2)` preserve the order !

Comment: That's a bit silly. Normally,  You'd just do `... | tee >(cmd1) >(cmd2)...`. It's the whole point of `>(...)` process substitution to expand to file paths which `tee` can open. Doing `tee /dev/fd/x x> >(cmd)`, becomes `tee /dev/fd/x x> /dev/fd/y` with that unnecessary addition of an extra fd re-opened on the pipe. In yash, where `>(...)` is *process redirection*, not *process substitution*, `tee /dev/fd/3 3>(cmd) /dev/fd/4 4>(cmd)` (note there's only  one `>` each time, it's a redirection) would make sense.

Comment: Thanks Stéphane, that's why I posted a simpler solution with _transparent_ `fd`'s processing under the hood. Which OS or Unix like use `yash` as default if any? (simple question, for real...)

Comment: @GillesQuénot, I don't know that any does yet.

Comment: OK, so why do you makes so such interest/focus usually  in this another `shell`? There's `fish` and others

Answer (score 4):

When you write `tee  /dev/fd/{10,11,12} 10> (…) 11> (…) 12> (…)`

The shell first creates the pipes, creates subprocesses (which inherit the pipes), close unused pipe ends and remap file directors. Then when the commands are executed, `/dev/fd/10` (or 11, or 12) can be opened.

The kernel only shows you available file descriptors. The `10>` redirection has a scope limited to its command.

If you want `strace` to show you `dup2`, you would best try `strace -ff bash -c "cmd1 >(cmd2)" 2>&1 | grep dup` for example.

Comment: That's because I use subprocesses that the kernel close `fd`'s ?

Comment: The shell creates the pipes before The subprocesses. Then the same pipe is inherited. But the shell closes used file descriptors in subprocesses and in its own process. The kernel does only what is asked by the shell. 

You can try `strace` like I have written without the `grep` filter, you will have multiple close syscall recorded.

Comment: Closes UNused file descriptors. Sorry for the typo